# Linear congruence. I need help solving $5 x − 7 \equiv 2 \pmod {17}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I understand how to solve linear congruence if the equation is in the form of, example: $4x \equiv 5 \pmod 9$ or $x+5\equiv 2 \pmod {11}.$

My problem is, I don't know exactly what to do with the $-7$ part of the $(5x - 7)$ equation.

Comment: Take it to the other side of equivalence. That is, $5x \equiv 2+7=9 \mod{17}$.

Comment: You can add or subtract the same number of both sides of the equivalence "$\equiv$ " sign, just like elementary algebra.

Comment: Hi! For $a,b,c\in Z, n\in Z^+$, we have $a\equiv b\pmod n\Rightarrow a+c\equiv b+c\pmod n$

Comment: How did you get $12x$?

Comment: Check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly format your posts

Comment: @JeremyJackson It can become $-12x\equiv 9\pmod{17}$ but not $12x\equiv 9\pmod{17}$

Answer (score 0):

write $$x\equiv \frac{9}{5}\mod 17$$ we will adding $17$ to the numerator untill it is divisible by $5$
$$x\equiv \frac{9}{5}\equiv \frac{26}{5}\equiv \frac{43}{5}\equiv \frac{60}{5}\equiv 12 \mod 17$$

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I understand it now

Comment: Alternatively, $5^{-1}\pmod{17}=7$ since $5\cdot 7=35\equiv 1\pmod{17}$, so $9/5\equiv9\cdot 7\equiv 63=51+12\equiv 12,$ with all $\equiv$ taken $\pmod{17}.$